# Any way to extract NUTS-3 shapefile of Germany from Eurostat' shapefile in R (updated)?

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal, europe

I have downloaded shapefile from Eurostat website ([download site for downloading Eurostat shapefile](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/) and [direct download link of Eurostat shapefile that I am interested in](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-03m.shp.zip)). To be short, I need shapefile of Germany' NUTS3 region only ([general concept for NUTS3](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/background)). To do so, I used `rgdal` package. Here is the R script down below:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-03m.shp.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url))
gunzip(basename(url))
rname <- list.files(getwd(), "shp$")
```

but I got following error anyway:

```
> eu <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

don't know why does this happen. Any quick solution? How can I fix this error?

If I fix this problem, I want to retrieve shapefile of only Germany's `NUTS3` region ([please take a look overview of NUTS3](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/background)). To do so, I come up with following solution:

```
nuts2 <- subset(eu, STAT_LEVL_ == 2)
proj4string(nuts2)
coordinates(point_data) <- ~LON + LAT
proj4string(point_data) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
point_data <- spTransform(point_data, proj4string(map_nuts2))
over(point_data, nuts2, by.id = TRUE)
```

My ultimate goal is to get Germany' NUTS3 level shapefile. How can I correct my above solution? How can I refine my above approach? Is there any more efficient and straightforward way to get certain countries' NUTS3 level shapefile? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution? Check if **filename exists**!

```r
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-03m.shp.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url))
unzip(basename(url))
rname <- list.files(getwd(), "shp$")

# your method
eu <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013")
## Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
##                    Cannot open layer

# another method
eu <- shapefile("NUTS_RG_03M_2013.shp")
## Error: file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not TRUE
```

You have a lot of files with the same pattern name:

```r
list.files(pattern = 'NUTS_RG_03M_2013.*.shp$')
## [1] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3035_LEVL_0.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3035_LEVL_1.shp"
## [3] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3035_LEVL_2.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3035_LEVL_3.shp"
## [5] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3035.shp"        "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3857_LEVL_0.shp"
## [7] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3857_LEVL_1.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3857_LEVL_2.shp"
## [9] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3857_LEVL_3.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_3857.shp"       
## [11] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4258_LEVL_0.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4258_LEVL_1.shp"
## [13] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4258_LEVL_2.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4258_LEVL_3.shp"
## [15] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4258.shp"        "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_0.shp"
## [17] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_1.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp"
## [19] "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_3.shp" "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326.shp"
```

One could be (for WGS 84 - EPSG 4326):

```r
eu <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
Germany <- eu[eu@data$CNTR_CODE == "DE",]
plot(Germany)
```

[image]

Comment: Please, one question at time

Comment: why there is no need for projection? Why there is no need to use spTransform and over utilities? Is your solution same with my second part of R script?

Comment: No need for projection? Really? I recommend you to search for basic tutorials of GIS and R on the internet. `spTransform` is for **re-project** from one CRS to other. I can't write anything about `over` because I don't know what `point_data` is